# How to add to hashmap from 2 jtextfields

Tags: java, hashmap, jtextfield

How do you take the values from two **`JTextField`** s and apply one to the key and one to the value of a **`HashMap`**?

This is what I have, but I think something isn't working right as I'm trying to search for this in a different code segment and nothing is coming up

```
if (capitalText.getText().equals("")) {
    capitalText.requestFocusInWindow();
}
else if (countryText.getText().equals("")) {
    countryText.requestFocusInWindow();
}
else {
    lm.addElement(capitalText.getText());
    capitalText.setText(value);
    countryText.setText(key);
    hashMap.put(key, value);

    // capitalText.getText();

    searchButton.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as

```
String key = keyTextField.getText();
String val = valTextField.getText();
hashMap.put(key, val);
```

If you can't find the value in the HashMap later on, then you might be searching for the wrong key?

Answer (score 0):

You must want to know the **Java swing or AWT** basics.
For getting a text from the `JTextField`.You want to use this

```
String text=capitalText.getText();//This will retrieve the value of the JTextField capitalText and store the it to the String variable named text.
```

For setting a value to the `JTextField`.You want to use this.

```
capitalText.setText("Some text");//This will set the String value "Some text" to the JTextField capitalText.
```

As your question.You can use this to achieve,What you are looking for.

```
String key=countryText.getText();
String value=capitalText.getText();
hashMap.put(key,val);
```

Iam sure this will help you.Have a great day.